# Preservation of Baumgartner's I-ultrafilters under various forcings

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, gn.general-topology, forcing, ultrafilters

For $I\subset \mathcal{P}(2^\omega)$, an ultrafilter $U$ on $\omega$ is said to be an I-ultrafilter if for all $f:\omega \to 2^\omega$, there exists $A\in U$ such that $f''[A]\in I$ [Baumgartner]. In practice the $I$ is usually taken to be a collection of sets with properties capturing "smallness". For example, $I$ consist of discrete/scattered/measure 0/nowhere dense subsets of $2^\omega$. P-point ultrafilters admit such nice $I$-characterization, namely take I to be the collection of subsets of reals whose order type in the natural real number ordering is at most $\omega$. See http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9311206 [Ultrafilters on omega by Baumgartner].

Given a forcing notion $P$, we say an ultrafilter $U$ is preserved by $P$ if in $V[G]$, $U$ generates an ultrafilter. There are some characterizations of ultrafilters of such class when $P$ is Sacks forcing, see https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/ultra-s.pdf by Miller. P-point ultrafilters are preserved under Sacks/Miller forcing. It has some connections with Halpern-Lauchli theorem.

I'm wondering how these properties interact with each other. More concretely, for any given $I$ and a forcing notion $P$ with some specific properties, how much we can say about whether all $I$-ultrafilters are preserved under $P$?

There are some results known:

- P-points are examples of $I$-ultrafilters preserved under Sacks/Miller forcing
- Under $MA$, there exists an ultrafilter preserved by Sacks forcing that is not discrete. This is the consequence of the fact that whenever $U$ is preserved under Sacks forcing, $U^\omega=\lim_U U_i, \forall i\in \omega \ U_i=U$ is still preserved under Sacks forcing while $U^\omega$ is not discrete anymore.

I'm wondering if there are some other related results known. Thanks!

Comment: Jing, this preprint http://www.math.toronto.edu/yyz22/2selfin.pdf contains a recent example of a kind of ultrafilter preserved by (side-by-side) Sacks. I suspect "selective ultrafilters" for most Ramsey spaces will have this property, but don't know if other examples have been worked out. I imagine these can be realized as $I$-ultrafilters, but haven't thought about the details.

Comment: @IianSmythe Interesting paper. For ordinary selective ultrafilters, I believe it is possible to realize them as I-ultrafilters (when I is an ideal of subsets of $\omega$, I remember Jana Flavskova had some characterizations). When $I\subset P(\mathbb{R})$, I'm not sure what suitable $I$ would characterize selective ultrafilters...